# .htaccess wildcard subfolder to another subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Here's my folder structure:

`{root}/pages/page1/index.php
 {root}/pages/page2/index.php
 {root}/pages/page3/index.php`

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When I go to `{root}/page1`, it checks the `/pages` subdirectory to see if there is a matching folder name, then it loads that folder. If not, it 404's. I would want this set with a wildcard so I wouldn't have to add it manually.

Comment: you mean this request {root}/page1 should assign to {root}/pages/page1/ otherwise 404?

Comment: @MohammedElhag Yep. Without rewriting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

At the main root directory `.htaccess` file put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/page1/
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)$     /pages/page1/$1 [L]
```

If you want a code to work with all in pages directory change it to this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/(.*)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$     /pages/$1/$2 [L]
```